# Outlier Treatment using Python

Tags: validation, machine-learning, outliers

I am a novice in Data Science and in the problem which I am trying to solve, I am stuck up with the outlier detection and treatment. Some of the insights about the dataset below:

- It's a regression problem
- Having both numerical and categorical features
- Numerical features include both discrete and continuous data columns
- Categorical features include mostly nominal & Ordinal data columns
- I've done the missing value imputation and categorical data transformation

I am stuck up since I don't know the way of outlier detection and treatment of numerical data. I request any of your valuable help in proceeding further.

Please let me know if you want any snapshot of the numerical data in order to give a solution.

I haven't added it since it's a generic doubt as I don't even know how and what to use for outlier detection and treatment.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with encryption, please don't tag spam.

Answer (score 0):

1. Plot the distribution of the numerical data
2. Do you see a normal distribution or a skewed distribution?
3. If it is normal. you can fairly take the median and 3 * median
4. Any value > 3* median is considered an outlier.